# How to Move Folder in WebDav using Sardine?

Tags: webdav, sardine

I am using Sardine client to move folder in WebDav. It is not working. But if it is file type it is working fine.

```
sardine.move("http://ip/webdav/kamesh/CloudDrive/test123","http://ip/webdav/kamesh/CloudDrive/Media/kmmm");
```

Please help me, what I need to do move folder?

Comment: Please also include the exact error you are getting when you run the code you posted.

Comment: Sorry i am not getting any error.Execution success.